# Не выводятся значения tv-параметров в pdoPage

Tags: modx

Не понимаю в чем может быть дело, потратил 2 дня на это,
вот вывод:

```
<div id="pdopage">
  <div class="rows">
    [[!pdoPage?
        &parents   =`6`
        &element   = `pdoMenu`
        &ajaxMode  =`default`
        &limit     =`3`
        &sortby    = `menuindex`
        &tplOuter  = `@INLINE <div class="offers_items">[[+wrapper]]</div>`
        &tpl       = `@INLINE [[$rent_item_page]]`
    ]]
  </div>
  [[!+page.nav]]
</div>
```

Здесь шаблон выводимого элемента:

```
<div class="expert-single">
    <div class="expert-img">

      [[+tv.specoffer:is=`spec`:then=`<b>Спецпредложение</b>`:else=``]]

      <a href="[[+link]]"><img src="[[+tv.image_item]]"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="expert-content text-center">
      <h3>[[+pagetitle]]</h3>
      <span>Офисное помещение</span>
      <p>18 500 руб. за м² в год</p>
      <p>[[+tv.price_month]] руб. в месяц</p>
      <a href="[[+link]]">Подробнее</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

В особенности волнует вывод изображения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в вызов `pdoPage` параметр `includeTVs` (Список ТВ-параметров для выборки, через запятую)

```
&includeTVs=`specoffer,image_item,price_month`
```

Для `pdoResources` чанки будут `[[+tv.specoffer]]`, для `pdoMenu` просто `[[+specoffer]]`

Comment: ес!) спасибо вам огромное